# Open links in embedded google documents in the same window and not inside the iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a site with embedded google documents.  The documents have links to other pages on the same site.  The documents are embedded using the embed code from the google document sharing, for example

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Rvul_FZYcdJEXFu8fRG5TB2cYgD-RFeiBuWbN44z5Gg/pub?embedded=true"></iframe>
```

I modify this slightly to

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Rvul_FZYcdJEXFu8fRG5TB2cYgD-RFeiBuWbN44z5Gg/pub?embedded=true" seamless width=600 height=1000 ></iframe>
```

If that is all I do then clicking on the links in the document, open the link inside the iframe, this then shows an entire webpage inside the iframe.

I did a lot of research and came up with the following code:

```
<iframe id="google-doc-iframe" srcdoc="" style="height: 1050px; margin: 0 auto;" align="middle" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="no"></iframe>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $.get("https://docs.google.com/document/d/1jcff6ihstj6aRVy_ojLir8briyW8afHyBYboZwCwUrY/pub?embedded=true", function(html) {
        $("#google-doc-iframe").attr("srcdoc", html);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#google-doc-iframe").contents().find('a[href^="http://"]').attr("target", "_parent");
            $("#google-doc-iframe").contents().find('a[href^="https://"]').attr("target", "_parent");
        }, 1000);
    });
});
</script>
```

This code worked fine, by using ajax to replace the link target attribute to the parent page.

Problem is that it doesn't work in IE 11.  The following error is generated:
SEC7118: XMLHttpRequest for https://docs.google.com/document/d/1jcff6ihstj6aRVy_ojLir8briyW8afHyBYboZwCwUrY/pub?embedded=true required Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).

I have looked for solutions to this, however my understanding of the code is limited and nothing I do seems to work.

Has anyone got any ideas for modifying my ajax script to work with CORS?

Comment: How did you not run into "No 'access-control-allow-origin' header is present on the requested resource" error ? I tried this, and no matter what browser I use, it fails at the $.get() method. Also, how did this allow you to access the contents of the iframe from an external Javascript method?

Comment: how did you solve this problem? I am facing the same issue now.