# Embed a Private Google Doc Using an iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, google-docs

Fellow Stackers, my intention is to embed a private Google Doc into a web page using an iframe, so that its contents only load for users who have been expressly shared on the Google Doc.

To do so, I'd like to use a link along these lines (https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/Export?exportFormat=html&format=html&id=[MyGoogleDocID]) to export the Google Doc as .html. Then, god willing, use JavaScript to render the exported .html file inside an iframe.

I'm new to JavaScript, but I've been using the following code (graciously [recommended by John](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28343653/open-links-in-embedded-google-documents-in-the-same-window-and-not-inside-the-if)) to force embedded hyperlinks within an iframe to open in a new window...so the task of loading a downloaded .html file seems within the realm of JavaScript's power:

```
<iframe id="myframe" srcdoc="" style="width: 600px; height: 500px; border: 0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $.get("https://docs.google.com/document/d/[MyGoogleSpreadsheetID]/pub?embedded=true", function(html) {
            $("#myframe").attr("srcdoc", html);
            setTimeout(function() {
                $("#myframe").contents().find('a[href^="http://"]').attr("target", "_blank");
                $("#myframe").contents().find('a[href^="https://"]').attr("target", "_blank");
            }, 1000);
        });
    });
</script>
```

As always, any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you looked in your JavaScript error console? I'd be surprised if there wasn't an error complaining about a same origin policy violation there.

Comment: An excellent question, sir, and no, my Google Chrome console indicates no errors of any kind. (NB: I hope my inclusion of this bit of JavaScript to open iframe links in a new window doesn't muddy the water of my original question. I merely included it to indicate why I thought JavaScript may ultimately provide a solution.)

Answer (score -1):

- edit: Google has an option for embedding forms (but not the other variety of documents):

  1. Go to File > Embed Form.
  2. Copy & Paste the embed code (it's already an iframe).
  3. Paste into your HTML document.

Comment: I'm unclear why my question was down-voted or why you referred to it as a "solution." My apologies if I'm misunderstanding something...but your answer does **not** allow me to "embed a private Google Doc into a web page using an iframe, so that its contents only load for users who have been expressly shared on the Google Doc." On the contrary, "Publish to the Web" would create a public copy of my private Google Doc, would it not?

Comment: Hi Greg, I actually didn't down-vote you; someone else did. You're right; the answer I provided only works for Google Forms. I've edited my response.

If not a form, what kind of document (spreadsheet, document, presentation) are you trying to share? That might help determine the best route for embedding.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, and my apologies for any unclarity in my use of "Google Doc." I'm attempting to embed a Google document.